# check_mk using ssh tunnels/ssh proxy

Tags: linux, monitoring, nagios, ssh-tunnel, check-mk

I'm trying to setup monitoring with `check_mk` and wanted to see if this is possible. My issue is as follows:

```
Layout:
Monitoring server:  1.1.1.1
Bastion server:     2.2.2.2
Host A:             localhost:1234
Host B:             localhost:5678
```

- All the machines are linux.
- The Monitoring server can connect to the Bastion server.
- The Bastion server can connect to all the host machines via ssh tunnels.

Is it possible to setup `check_mk` with the above setup?

Comment: We use check_mk over ssh for remote nodes, though not with a bastion server. It appears though, by googling "check_mk ssh" and clicking on the second answer, that you can: http://lists.mathias-kettner.de/pipermail/omd-users/2014-May/000847.html . Further info from official documentation http://mathias-kettner.de/checkmk_datasource_programs.html

Comment: Thaks for the link, i'll give it a go and will report back on findings.